# Raspberry PI - Slim API not working with Routes

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, slim, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to built some Rest api on Raspberry PI model B with Slim Framework. The problem is that when i run the / route all work fine, when i try to run /test route i have a 404.

I think there are some problem with the .htaccess and rewrite rule, this is my structure of the api:

```
var/www/html/   is the root
--api
 --libs
    --Slim
 --index.php
 --.htaccess
```

and this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [PT,L]
```

and this is my index.php slim app:

```
<?php
require '/var/www/html/api/libs/Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/', function() use($app) {

    echo "Root";

}); 

$app->get('/test', function() use($app) {

   echo "test";

}); 

$app->run();

?>
```

Thanks in advance

**Solution:**

I've edited the file in etc/apache2/apache2.config changing these line

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None    <----- this to All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then restarting apache2 with

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

and i'll need also this line

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

thanks @T0xicCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apache configuration (check in */etc/apache2/*) needs to have `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All` for the directory where your files are (*/var/www/html* or */var/www/html/api*). Otherwise apache will simply ignore the *.htaccess* and try to find a folder or a file named `test`. See the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride).